# Soft sheaves adapted to $f_!$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, category-theory, homological-algebra, sheaf-theory

I'm reading Gelfand-Manin, Homological Algebra. I understand that the class of soft sheaves is sufficiently large, because every injective sheaf is soft. Now to see that this class is adapted to $f_!$, I have to show that every acyclic complex of soft sheaves is mapped by the functor $f_!$ to an acyclic complex.

For this, I'd say it's enough to just show that if 
$0\rightarrow \mathcal{F}\rightarrow \mathcal{G}\rightarrow\mathcal{H}\rightarrow 0$ 
is an exact sequence of soft sheaves, then $0\rightarrow \mathcal{f_!F}\rightarrow \mathcal{f_!G}\rightarrow\mathcal{f_!H}\rightarrow 0$ is also exact.

But in the book, they say the above is only enough because of an exercise from earlier which says that in an exact sequence of sheaves $0\rightarrow \mathcal{F}\rightarrow \mathcal{G}\rightarrow\mathcal{H}\rightarrow 0$ , if $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{G}$ are soft, then so is $\mathcal{H}$.

Can somebody tell me where this exercise is needed in the proof of the adaptedness of soft sheaves to $f_!$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, to show that $f_!$ takes acyclic complexes of soft sheaves to acyclic complexes, we need to split up an acyclic complex of soft sheaves
$$0 \to \mathcal F_1 \xrightarrow{\phi_1} \mathcal F_2 \xrightarrow{\phi_2} \mathcal F_3 \xrightarrow{\phi_3} \mathcal F_4 \xrightarrow{\phi_4} \dots$$
into short exact sequences, namely
$$0 \to \mathcal F_1 \xrightarrow{\phi_1} \mathcal F_2 \xrightarrow{\phi_2} \text{im}(\phi_2) \to 0,$$
$$0 \to \text{im}(\phi_2) \to \mathcal F_3 \to \text{coker} (\phi_2) \to 0,$$
$$0 \to \text{coker}(\phi_2) \xrightarrow{\phi_3} \mathcal F_4 \xrightarrow{\phi_4} \text{im}(\phi_4) \to 0,$$ and so on.

Showing that $f_!$ preserves the acyclicity of our complex is equivalent to showing that it preserves these short exact sequences. This does *not* immediately follow from the assertion that $f_!$ preserves short exact sequences of soft sheaves, however, as we need to know that $\text{im}(\phi_2)$, $\text{coker}(\phi_2)$, $\text{im}(\phi_4)$, etc. are soft. This is where the earlier exercise is needed.

Comment: Right, makes sense. Was quite the stupid question in retrospect. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It is not needed in the proof, it just makes it easier. Because of that exercise you only need to prove that $f_!$ is right exact.

Comment: @Marco Armenta But $f_!$ is left-exact by definition (for all sheaves). The point is that it's exact only for soft sheaves. I still don't see what the exercise has to do with that.

Comment: @ironcastle: Sorry, needed an edition, I was suppose to say "right exact". And you're right, it is necessary and sufficient to prove that $f_!$ preserves short exact sequences, actually, this is true for every abelian category, so it must be true also for sheaves. Now I have the same doubt as you.